# Searching Duplicate String Complexity

Tags: java, string, time-complexity, big-o

I have a task to find duplicate elements and write a method to return a boolean value.

Code below is what I have for it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DuplicateEle {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] arr = { "hello", "hi", "hello", "howru" };
        DuplicateEle de = new DuplicateEle();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            boolean isDup = de.isDuplicate(arr[i]);
            System.out.println(arr[i]+" is duplicate :" +isDup);
        }
    }

    List<String> dList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private boolean isDuplicate(String str) {
        boolean isDup = false;
        if (dList.contains(str)) {
            isDup = true;
        } else
            dList.add(str);
        return isDup;
    }

}
```

It works as expected. 
output :

```
hello is duplicate :false
hi is duplicate :false
hello is duplicate :true
howru is duplicate :false
```

I want to find the time complexity for the above code. I am looking into the tutorial for time complexity about how it works like this [one](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/).

Can someone please give me inputs on the above code and help me understand how time complexity works please ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: just use the link you give. they explain everything . @lexicore love the link :D

Comment: @lexicore: Not sure if I understood that. Reasoning as in ? more specific about the task ?

Comment: @lr14 You throw a task upon us, you even have a guide how to do this and then you ask for "inputs" and "help me understand". What do you expect, should someone sit down with you and help you read that guide and apply it to your task? Not going to happen. If you actually try to apply what's written in the guide you linked to and then write down your reasoning in your question and ask if anyone could spot errors, then you might get some actual help. But as it stands now you simply ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am tempted to copy paste the link content ... this is well explained ...

Comment: @lexicore - when I say inputs , m asking if there are any errors in the program.  As for time complexity  - I was thinking based on the tutorial its O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making your code way too complicated, use a `HashSet<String>`, which will guarantee uniqueness and will return whether the element was already in the set.

```
public class DuplicateEle {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
      String[] arr = { "hello", "hi", "hello", "howru" };

      for (String word : arr) {
        boolean unique = seen.add(word);
        System.out.printf("%s is duplicate: %b%n", word, !unique);
      }
    }
}
```

Using a `HashSet` is very efficient as it will use the `int` hash of the string to find the bucket, only then needing to use `equals` to do a full 'expensive' equals.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you !!  Can you also post some tutorials for understanding time complexity better please ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, `n` is the number of elements to be checked and `m` is the size of the longest word. So, you go through the array of elements and for each element you check if its in the `dList`.

At the starts, its empty, so with time, you add elements. So, question is, how fast is method [contains](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.contains%28java.lang.Object%29). If you look at the source code of `ArrayList`, you will see that it goes through the array and check for each element is it [equal](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29), and that is done by checking each character starting from the end (first it checks if they are equal size).

So worst case is that all elements are equal size and they are different at the first element. So, at the first element, you do nothing, so base operations counts as 1. At the step 2, you do 1 checking, at step 3, you do 2 checking, etc and at step n you do n-1 checking of contains. So, you have:

```
 0+1+2+...+n-1 = n(n-1)/2
```

Now, worst case scenario, each element are the same size and they are different at the first elements, so you have another loop of the size `m`. Here, `m` can also represent average string size or statistical expectation of the position of different `char` at the string (from the end).

So, its `O(mn^2)`, but if we say there is some randomness in `m`, we can say its `Ω(n^2)`.

But I got a good news for you. There is faster way, by using `HashSet`. You just need to change dList with some HashSet, and place each element in it as you go through the initial list, so checking each element will be done in `O(1)`, which means, overall speed will be `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining about the  time complexity for Arraylist in detail. Also can you post some tutorial links on complexity if any.

Comment: Well, you should first study little bit of math, to be precise, Sequences and Series. Try this https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/big-o/0/1. It should give you some practical experience to understand algorithm complexity. But, it would be best for you to read some books on this subject, since this is to complex and applies a lot of math to be covered in some web tutorials. I recommend this book: "The Algorithm Design Manual" by Steve S. Skiena.

Comment: Thats helpful. Will look into it. Thank you !